# IP configuration problems with two Unifi APs with same SSID?

Tags: wireless-networking, ip, wireless-access-point

So recently I installed two Unifi APs in my house, one upstairs and one downstairs. They're working fine mainly, but I'm running into a curious problem with some of my devices. If I am downstairs, I can see and connect to the SSID of the house (both units broadcast this SSID) but in a certain location, I get a "connected, no internet" error. If I trouble shoot, I get a message about invalid IP configuration. Given the location of the house where this error occurs, I suspect there is some confusion about identifying APs, but its a rather irritating problem. Should I simply have two separate SSIDs on both devices, or is this a way to resolve such IP problems more readily?

Comment: What are both APs connected to?

Comment: Hi there - the APs are connected to an Ethernet switch in this house. The network set up itself is quite complex: The actual router is in the main building, and then we have laid fibre optic cable to bring it to this particular house on the same ground but 350 metres away, with all the splitters etc required. But ultimately, it goes into a switch, which powers the APs...

Comment: That's good enough as long as both APs actually serve the same VLAN for the same SSID. Are you using VLAN tagging in UniFi or in the switch?